# Can I charge my laptop with powerbank?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, safety, laptop, powerbanks

I have a Lenovo laptop with a L16L2PB3 lithium-ion battery. It has 4610mAh capacity which is enough for 3-4 hours of power. I want to have an ability to charge it when no sockets are around and for this purpose I want to use an existing Xiaomi Powerbank (PLM05ZM) with 20000mAh capacity which I bought a few years back. I want to make sure that it suits my laptop, so I won't accidentally kill it.

So specs for the battery are:

- I suppose input is from 7,6V-8,7V with 4,61A

[image: L16L2PB3]

Possible outputs for powerbank are:

- 5,1V and 2,4A if two devices connected simultaneously
- 9V and 2A
- 12V and 1,5A

[image]

Currently I'm using a 65W Lenovo charger (ADLX65CLGE2A) for charging my 35Wh battery. From the the output of `upower` in linux, I deduced that my laptop uses 7,6V and ~2,4A for charging. So it is 18Wh and so it happens that my powerbank can also output maximum of 18Wh.

[image]

The only thing that I'm concerned about is voltage. The closest suitable available voltage for my laptop is 9V, but the laptop battery states that it accepts the maximum of 8,7V.

So my question is: Is it safe to charge my laptop with powerbank with output of 9V and 2A or it will kill my laptop? Or will it automatically switch to 5V and 1A since I'll be using an USB to 4,0x1,7mm DC adapter. (the one that my laptop uses)

Comment: What does the mains adaptor for your laptop output?

Comment: @HandyHowie it outputs 20.0V and 3.25A

Comment: Are you asking if you can power a 20v device with only 5/9/12v output? Probably not, at least not without a voltage converter.

Comment: @user1850479 I guess 20v is charger's maximum output, since my laptop uses only 18Wh of that charger (excuse me if my terms are incorrect). My question is at the end of the post.

Comment: Presumably you are wanting to charge the laptop by plugging your powerbank into where you connect the mains adaptor into your laptop.  If so, your powerbank will need to output the same voltage as the mains adaptor.

Comment: Your terms are incorrect. The laptop will take 20V in and that's all. Internally it'll step that down to charge the battery but you really don't want to bypass that and connect to the battery directly. You CAN find 12V in to 20V (car battery laptop adapters) : whether your powerbank can drive one of these is another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely won't work.

You are missing three key things:

1. Your laptop DC input expects a specific voltage (20V) and likely anything substantially different will cause problems.
2. The DC input voltage your laptop receives has nothing to do with the battery voltages. Your laptop has internal battery management circuits, which possibly charge using current or voltage profiles that are different than the nominal voltages marked on the battery pack.
3. Your USB powerbank will only supply 5V unless the connected device is QuickCharge compatible. The connected device needs to "negotiate" or "trigger" a higher voltage, and that won't happen through the laptop DC jack.